# Fail to start MGS_VeyronHost_x64_Bandit service

Tags: bandit

[image: Services error message]

Got this error message when trying to start the MGS_VeyronHost_x64_Bandit service manually.

Confirm the Parchment, Game Service, and MGS_VeyronProxy service are running.

Environment info: Axiom GTP93, APP1 - 10.247.173.148